# $\|f\|\le 2$,$|f(x_o)|\le 6$, then $\|x_0\|\le 3$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a Banach Space, $x_0\in X$.

Suppose that for any $f\in X'$ (space of linear bdd functions) with $\|f\|\le 2$ we have $|f(x_o)|\le 6$.

How to show: $\|x_0\|\le 3$

could you please help with this question.

Answer (score 2):

Use Hahn-Banach : Suppose $\|x_0\| > 3$, then $\exists f \in X'$ such that $\|f\| = 1$ and $f(x_0) = \|x_0\|$. Hence, $\|2f\| \leq 2$, but
$$
|2f(x_0)| = 2\|x_0\| > 6
$$

Comment: I didn't understand how did you use the Hanh-Banach Thm here

Comment: This is a corollary: For any $x\in X, \exists f\in X'$ such that $\|f\| = 1$ and $f(x) = \|x\|$